# How can a vector be multiplied by itself ?

Tags: linear-algebra

Well I'm reading a paper and this simple least squares equation is not making sense to me .. This is the equation

$$\mathbf a=\underset{\mathbf a}{\arg\min}\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\mathbf a^T\mathbf x_i-y_i\right)^2$$

A little background on this equation:

basically this equation is being used for finding a mapping which takes some high dimensionality data (**x**), and maps it to some low dimensional data (**y**). The mapping transformation matrix (**a**) is what we have to find. The mapping should be such that we minimize the error between the original and projected data (as you can probably tell) ..

Inside the summation, **y** and **x** are being accessed serially in a column by column manner, and so *yi* and *xi* (i being the subscript) are referring to individual columns of matrices **y** and **x**, respectively .. Also, as you can probably tell, both **y** and **x** contain the same number of columns, *m*. Only the number of rows they each have is different ..

Now here's my question .. As far as I can tell (and I'm virtually sure I'm correct here), the result of the evaluation being performed inside the brackets would result in a column vector ... And then this column vector is being squared !? That is, this is what the equation is suggesting:

( *column vector here* )2 ...... with 2 being the superscript here

How is this possible ? Or is the equation maybe referring to a dot product here ?

Comment: Could you post the paper you're looking at, for reference?

Comment: Its equation (9) in this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.9676&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 5):

Yes Ahmad, you are absolutely right the equation is referring to the dot product. Given a (real) vector $\mathbf{v}$, one conventionally defines
$$\mathbf{v}^2 = \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{v} = \sum_j v_j^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I recall someone posting a similar answer yesterday, but it seems to be removed. Reading your pdf, I am pretty sure that $\mathbf{a}$ is in fact a vector, not a matrix (well, an $n\times 1$-matrix).

In Section 2.1 one introduces a matrix $X=[\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_m]$, so each $\mathbf{x}_i$ is a column vector. In Section 2.2 one takes the argmin of some expression involving $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}_i$, where $\mathbf{a}$ is such that $\mathbf{a}^TXDX\mathbf{a}=1$ (where $D$ is a diagonal matrix). Clearly then, $\mathbf{a}$ is a column vector and $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}_i$ is the dot product, resulting in a scalar. In Theorem 1 just before equation (9), $\mathbf{a}$ is called an eigen-*vector*.

So one takes the vector $\mathbf{a}$ which minimizes the *scalar* expression $\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\mathbf a^T\mathbf x_i-y_i\right)^2$.

Comment: . well looking again into the paper I agree that **a** is being called an eigen- _vector_ at one stage and I'll look into that, but I dont get your logic with saying that **a** is a column vector because _a(transpose)XDXa=1_ .. I dont get what you mean here ..